Remove square matching brackets but only those which do not have a white space inside bracket
Having looked at this answer: Remove square brackets if content within the square bracket does not contain spaces
This works fine for Notepad++ but when I take the Notepad++ solution and put it in C# I get all sorts of bad string replacements.
I have this now:
C# looks like this:
str.Regex.Replace(str, @"\[(\w+)\]|\[([^\]]+)\]"), "(?1$1:(?2"$2"))")

So if I have this:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date Started] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [AudioLocation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [PlayerLocation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Event] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

I want to remove only the unnecessary brackets and get this:
CREATE TABLE dbo.Event(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    "Date Started" datetime NOT NULL,
    StartTime time(7) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(250) NULL,
    AudioLocation nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    PlayerLocation nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_dbo.Event PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED


Essentially your question is, What is the .NET syntax for referring to the matched groups in a regex substitution.

I think you just need Regex.Replace(str, @"\[(\w+)\]", "$1")

@Charlieface [Date Started] => "Date Started" I guess if there is a whitespace, double quotes should be wrapped around (OP please correct me if I'm wrong).

@user3297833 Your goal is not clear, the conditional replacement from your current pattern is using a Boost feature (replacement conditional). The logic of your sample removes square brackets if there is no white-space (only word characters) inside brackets but wraps double quotes around the others, e.g. if there is a space inside. Please clarify...

@bobblebubble If you mean that it would get wrapped in quotes because of the "$1", no that's normal C# quotes. I guess @"[""\[](\w+)[\]""]" would do it for cases when the values themselves in the text are wrapped in quotes not brackets.

In your example you've simply removed all open and closed brackets ('[' and ']'). What are "necessary brackets"?

@CarySwoveland Necessary brackets are those that enclose names with spaces in them. Those are replaced with "", the rest are removed.

I believe that replacing just at once is not a necessary requirement for this question.
Why not just use Regex.Replace twice:
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = 
            @"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event](
                [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                [Date Started] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
                [Description] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
                [AudioLocation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
                [PlayerLocation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Event] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED";

        string pattern = @"\[([\w.]+)\]";
        str = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, "$1");

        pattern = @"\[(.+)\]"; 
        // or as per the suggestion in the comment below: pattern = @"\[([^\]]+)\]";
        str = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, "\"$1\"");

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}

First replaces [ID], [int], [PK_dbo.Event] etc.
Second - [Date Started].

In your second replacement I would prefer to use negated [^\]]* (like in OP's sample) instead of the dot .+ to prevent skipping over any ].

Something like this should work:
public static string RemoveBracketsIfSingleWord(string inputString)
{
    // Regex pattern to match single words enclosed in square brackets without whitespace
    string pattern = @"\[([^\]\s]+)\]";

    // Replace matches with the captured word without brackets
    return Regex.Replace(inputString, pattern, "$1");
}

You can call this method as below:
string s = 
""""
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date Started] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [AudioLocation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [PlayerLocation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Event] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
"""";

Console.WriteLine(RemoveBracketsIfSingleWord(s));

I'm using interpolated strings to have multiline text that doesn't look garbled.
The code is self-explanatory.

I should add that I did not replace brackets with quotes as your output does. However, that can be a simple string replace of square brackets with quotes in the context of SQL.

Your Notepad++ replacement strings says: if Group 1 matched, replace with Group 1 value, if Group 2 matched, replace the match with Group 2 value enclosed in double quotation marks.
In C#, you can write
Regex.Replace(str, @"\[(\w+)]|\[([^]]+)]", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : $"\"{m.Groups[2].Value}\"")

See the C# demo online:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = @"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date Started] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [AudioLocation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [PlayerLocation] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Event] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED";
        var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[(\w+)]|\[([^]]+)]", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : $"\"{m.Groups[2].Value}\"");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}

Output:
CREATE TABLE dbo.Event(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    "Date Started" datetime NOT NULL,
    StartTime time(7) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(250) NULL,
    AudioLocation nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    PlayerLocation nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "PK_dbo.Event" PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED


FYI, just noticed the double quotes in the replacement, so I have fixed the code and the online demo.
